# get balance from entities for all customers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table account

```
id - name
1 - Lab
2 - Sara
3 - Jone
```

table entities

```
id - credit - debit - value
1      1        3      10
1      1        2      20
1      3        1      5
1      2        1      3
```

I want the balance for all customers the output :

```
Name - balance
Sara     17
Jone     5
```

Comment: how do you arrive at the `balance`?you should explain that a bit better.

Comment: The way it's worded, I would expect Sara to be -17 and Jone to be -5 (Sara was debited 20, then credited 3; Jone was debited 10 then credited 5).

Comment: that's right Adams V

Comment: What's the `id` column in the `entities` table? Shouldn't that be unique for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select account.name, (plus.balance - minus.balance) as balance 
from accounts inner join
(select credit as id, sum(value) as balance from entities group by credit) as plus 
inner join 
(select debit as id, sum(value) as balance from entities group by debit) as minus 
on plus.id = minus.id and accounts.id = plus.id
```

explanation- I'm making two copies from entities table- one to sum the credit (per id) and one to sum the debit, and then joins both of them with the accounts table to get the name. Not sure what you do with the id column in the entity table, seems redundant.

Comment: Might want to add some null protection for accounts who are missing either a credit or a debit, but besides that, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

didn't work the errur invalid token ')' at line 6

```
select "Accounts".name, (plus.balance - minus.balance) as balance 
from 
"Accounts" inner join
(select public.entities.accounts_id_credit as id, sum(value) as balance from public.entities group by public.entities.accounts_id_credit) as plus 
inner join 
(select public.entities.accounts_id_debit as id, sum(value) as balance from public.entities group by public.entities.accounts_id_debit) as minus
on plus.id = minus.id and "Accounts".id = plus.id
```